# What is the simplest way to perform a Cavendish experiment?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, home-experiment

The [Cavendish experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavendish_experiment) is cool, but seems complicated to experimentally perform. What is a simple way to recreate the experiment?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/356/2451

Comment: well, because the Earth is so much more massive than the equipment or objects of your experiment, it's not surprizing that it will be difficult to measure the gravitational attraction of the adjacent object (which is much, much less massive than the Earth) when such is added to the gravitational attraction of the planet your experiment is on.  i wonder if they did some kind of measure of $G$ in the shuttle or ISS?  or if the rooskies did something like that?

Comment: hey, it's not big $G$ on the cheap, but if you want to see how physicists perform the Cavendish experiment today, check out [the U Washington apparatus](http://asd.gsfc.nasa.gov/Stephen.Merkowitz/G/Big_G.html), including [this time-lapse video of it in operation](http://asd.gsfc.nasa.gov/Stephen.Merkowitz/G/M_Big_G_1.html).

Comment: say, i found a [short physics course .pdf doc](http://courses.umass.edu/phys440/bigg.pdf) that makes an interesting reference to **C. L. Stong, *"How to repeat Cavendish's experiment for determining the constant of gravity"*,
The Amateur Scientist column in Scientific American, September 1963, p267**.  good luck finding a copy.

Comment: A Cavendish experiment is rather easy to perform these days, since you can measure tiny movements with capacitive sensors or a simple optical interferometer with very high accuracy. This leaves you with the usual problems of working on a very solid table anchored to a large foundation (concrete mix is dirt cheap!), getting a bunch of lead balls and finding a torsion fiber that does not suffer from non-linearities and memory effects, but other people have done the hard work for you, see e.g. http://www.physics.uci.edu/gravity/papers/icifuasPaper.pdf. Good luck!

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson the following links to the SciAm article you mentioned - but it is behind a paywall. http://www.nature.com/scientificamerican/journal/v209/n3/pdf/scientificamerican0963-267.pdf . People with institutional access should be able to see it though.

Comment: Just appeared in Physics Today: http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/magazine/physicstoday/news/10.1063/PT.5.2025 - I must say what they describe was not a measurement of G (although they claim it was). Maybe it is too harsh to say this is a description of "how not to do it"... Leaving that up to you to decide

Comment: @floris Just found that experiment and was skeptical about it as well, what do you mean with not being a measurement of G?

Comment: @Jon they say so themselves: “some of them wished we could have calibrated the torsion balance”. Also no attempt to compare the observed acceleration to the expected. 10 minutes to travel 6”? What mass would you need? Easy to compute… orders of magnitude off.

Answer (score 3):

The way Cavendish did it would seem to be simplest - it can be done with 18th Century technology.

In practice its very difficult to do in a lab, alternately it is a very good way to demonstrate the resonant properties of concrete lab buildings.

If you wanted to try it for yourself then a garden shed, with an insulated inner room/box built of plywood and styrofoam and a vibration proof table made from stacks of inner tubes and paving slabs, and a telescope+webcam so you can keep it completely sealed. Seems plausible.

Comment: What is C18 technology?

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance, sorry 18th Century, it's standard history shorthand at least in British English.
The experiment was done in 1799